# Android - when to delete sent attachment

Tags: java, android, email, gmail, attachment

I have a small app, where user can save his GPS locations. These locations are saved to .txt file. When the user is done, he should send this file to his email. Adding a locations shouldn't be canceled by onPause or onDestroy method.
But when I try to delete the file after sending it via GMail, it sends no attachment (because the file had been deleted before gmail sent it - sometimes user has to open GMail manually and refresh it). So when is the right moment for deleting the file?